# Some files in Documents subfolders cannot be access while device is locked / screen is off

Tags: swift, core-audio, ios13

Some files in Documents subfolders cannot be accessed while the device is locked.

`AVAudioFile(forReading: currentPlaylistURLs[index!])`

The above line will throw an error when the device is locked or screen is off and the URL is to some file in some subfolder in the Documents folder. Not all subfolders cause an error (Why??). When a device is unlocked there is no error. I noticed this behavior in iOS 13.2.3 so it was working fine prior to this version.

**Error is:**

```
[AVAudioFile.mm:134:AVAudioFileImpl: (ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, &_extAudioFile)): error -54
Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=-54 "(null)" UserInfo={failed call=ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, &_extAudioFile)}
```

Has anyone experience this?

Comment: try writing your files with no protection `write(to: fileURL, options: .noProtection)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/encrypting_your_app_s_files

Comment: @LeoDabus App does not write the files. Files were transferred via air drop, opened with Files app then saved into the app's Documents subfolder. Subfolder was created from the Files app while saving.

Comment: **To change the data protection level of an existing file, use the setResourceValue(_:forKey:) method of NSURL. When calling this method, assign the new data protection option to the fileProtectionKey resource key. Listing 2 shows an example that adds this key to an existing file.**

Comment: @LeoDabus Per your suggestion, I set it to .none before initializing the AVAudioFile but I still get the same error on the same line.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks anyway. I am pretty sure this is an iOS bug. I was hoping to find a workaround..

Comment: Try setting the enclosing folder file protection key

Comment: @LeoDabus changing the file permission seems to be the right solution for a workaround. Strangely, setting the file permission right before instantiating AVAudioFile from it isn't fast enough. Looping through the list whenever it's gets fresh list seems to have fixed this error. I also have to set the permission for a single file when ever a new file gets added to the list as well. If you want to, you can add an answer and I'll mark it. I'll experiment with setting the directory permission instead of looping through all the files. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your file's file protection key permission to `.none` and its parent folder as well:

```
extension URL {
    var parentDirectory: URL? { try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.parentDirectoryURLKey]).parentDirectory }
    var fileProtection: URLFileProtection? { try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileProtectionKey]).fileProtection }
    func disableFileProtection() throws { try (self as NSURL).setResourceValue(URLFileProtection.none, forKey: .fileProtectionKey) }
}
```

---

```
let fileURL = URL.init(...)
if let parentDirectory = fileURL.parentDirectory {
    do {
        try parentDirectory.disableFileProtection()
        try fileURL.disableFileProtection()
    }
    catch { print(error) }
}
```